# C: use of fgets() with file

Tags: c, file, fgets

Good evening StackOverFlow.
I typed a code which uses lists and files to manage an address book, now I have a problem with the function fgets(). 
In the procedure **print_file()** I used fgets() to read a line from the file and to store it into a string of, at the most, 200 characters. Debugging my code, I noticed that the file was popularized but after I extract the line with fgets() to store it into the string, the string results empty. Following I post the procedure **print_file()** and the procedure **filling()** which popularized the file with the nodes of the list. Anyone can help me?

```
void print_file(FILE* myfile, int num){
    char contact[200];
    int i=0;

    while(i<num){ 
        fgets(contact, 200, myfile);
        i++;
        printf("%d) %s", i, contact);
    }
    fclose(myfile);
}


void filling(FILE* myfile){
    list_struct* l; node_struct* new_node;
    node_struct* tempnode;
    t_contact temp;
    int n_contacts=0, i=0;

    printf("\n*****The file will be filled by a list*****\n");

    l=made_list(); //creating new list
    if(l!=NULL){
        printf("\nList successfully created\n");
    }
    printf("How many contacts do you want to add to the list?   ");
    scanf("%d", &n_contacts);

    for(i=1;i<=n_contacts;i++){
        printf("NAME > ");
        scanf("%s", temp.name);
        printf("SURNAME > ");
        scanf("%s", temp.surname);
        printf("TELEPHONE > ");
        scanf("%s", temp.telephone);
        printf("E-MAIL > ");
        scanf("%s", temp.email);
        printf("\n");
        new_node = made_node(temp); //creating new node
        add_node(l, new_node);
    }// end for --> the list has been popularized

    tempnode = l->head;
    while(tempnode!=NULL){
        fprintf(myfile, "%s %s %s %s\n", tempnode->content.name,   tempnode->content.surname, tempnode->content.telephone, tempnode->content.email);
        tempnode=tempnode->next;
    }
    print_file(myfile, n_contacts);
    fclose(myfile);
```

}

Comment: you need `fflush` and `rewind` or `fseek`.  also `fclose(myfile);` at `filling` : `fclose` call twice.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written it, fgets() will get called to read starting at the end-of-file.  You can use fseek() to position to the start of file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reposition the file pointer at the start of the file in order to read from it. As you have it now it is at the end of the file when you call print_file.

`rewind(fp)` should do it.

### EDIT:

based on your comment I would propose something like this instead
note also that you are calling `fclose()` twice one time inside `print_file` and
another time after you call `print_file`, this is definitely not good. Instead remove the `fclose` from the `print_file` function since the name implies that it only prints.

```
/* 
 * extracts a row from the file and then puts it into 
 * a string and prints the result
 * @param[in] myFile file pointer to file opened in rw access
 * @param[in] num number of rows in the file 
 */
void print_file(FILE* myfile, int num)
{
  char contact[200];  // allocate on stack
  int i = 0;

  if ( myfile != NULL )  // check argument to function
  {
    fflush(myfile);
    rewind(myfile);

    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
      if (fgets(contact, sizeof(contact), myfile) != NULL);
      {
        printf("%d) %s", i + 1, contact);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

alternatively you could just read from start of file to end of file by reading each line and not caring about `num`:

```
  int i = 1;
  while (fgets(contact, sizeof(contact), myfile) != NULL);
  {
    printf("%d) %s", i++, contact);
  }
```

Comment: `void print_file(FILE* myfile, int num){
 
        char *contact;
 int i=0;

 fflush(myfile);
 rewind(myfile);
 while(i<num){ //extracts a row from the file and then puts it into a string and prints the result
  free(contact);
  contact=calloc(200, sizeof(char));
  fgets(contact, 200, myfile);
  i++;
  printf("%d) %s", i, contact);
  contact=NULL;
 }
 fclose(myfile);
}`

Did I write right?

Comment: you got a memory leak in that code. contact = NULL after printf

Comment: I took off **contact=NULL** after printf but the string contact still empty after the fgets()

Comment: how do you open the file? did you check if the file is created?

Comment: did you check the contents of the file? is there anything in it?

Comment: I debugged the code and the file is popularized by the fprintf(), so there are contents in the file

Comment: Char filename [100]; FILE* myfile; myfile=fopen(filename, "w");

Comment: You need to open the file in both read and write mode, you only open it in write mode with "w" , instead write "rw" or if you are on windows "rwt"